# Add control from class which inherit link button control on webpage

Tags: vb.net

I created the customer linkbutton in class. I can add it by code in grid view.  If I want to add it on design view. Is it possible? If so, would you tell me how? Thanks in advance.

For example:

```
  <TempLinkbutton id="btnEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btnWider" Text="Edit"  Visible="true"/>
```

There is my code:

```
Public Class TempLinkbutton
Inherits LinkButton
Private NewPropertyValue As String


Public Property LinkTarget() As String
    Get
        Return NewPropertyValue
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        NewPropertyValue = value
    End Set
End Property


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom server controls directly onto aspx pages. There is a lot you can do with server controls but here is how to start off.

First, if your `TempLinkButton` is located in a separate library you will need to add a reference to the class library for your web project if not already.

Second, on the page you want to use the control, you must register the assembly and namespace for where your `TempLinkButton` is located.

For example, if your `TempLinkButton` is in a library called `CustomControls`

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Assembly="CustomControls" Namespace="CustomControls" %>
```

Or it can be done in the web.config so it applies to all pages

```
<system.web>    
 <pages>
   <controls>
     <add tagPrefix="cc" Assembly="CustomControls" 
       namespace="CustomControls">
     </add>
   </controls>
 </pages>
</system.web>
```

Using whatever you defined for `TagPrefix`, you can now start using it.

```
<cc:TempLinkButton id="btnEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btnWider" Text="Edit"  Visible="true" />
```

If you added the reference and did the register/web.config correctly, once you start typing `<cc:`, you should see your `TempLinkButton` and any other ones within the same assembly and namespace that you registered.

So quite similar to a user control in using it.

Here is a [decent article](http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/creating-a-custom-web-server-control-in-asp-net-using-visual-studio-2010/) about custom server controls although the code besides the ASPX is in c#. It also talks about having the controls in the toolbox, defining attributes and so on.

You can also refer to msdn [Walkthrough: Developing and Using a Custom Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx)

Comment: thanks your detail explanation. My vb page is on the folder of website. It doesn't have namespace. Do I need to add it? For example: if the namespace is "TestNameSpace" and class name is "TempLinkbutton". How can I reference it. Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks your detail explanation. My vb page is on the other folder of website. It doesn't have namespace. I try to added the namespace. When I run the page, I got an error, Could not load file or assembly. Thanks in advance. Is something I did wrong?

Comment: @user819774 are you saying that the TempLinkButton is located in the web project (where all your aspx pages are)? Usually they aren't, but if that is the case, I believe it is Assembly="YourWebProjectName" and Namespace="YourWebProjectName". If you did add a namespace TestNameSpace (you don't have to), it is Namespace="YourWebProjectName.TestNameSpace". I'll update my answer if this helps.